# How to use rsync with --delete while leaving non-backupped directories intact?

Tags: rsync

I know that there are quite a number of “rsync and symlinks” threads, but I can’t find one that applies to my problem.

I want to use rsync to make backup copies of a `/home` partition, with the added twist that /home contains some real home directories and some symlinks to another file system:

```
/home/user1 (a directory)
/home/user2 (a symlink to another fs)
```

I try to use:

```
rsync -axv --delete /home /some_backup/
```

Where `/some_backup` already contains:

```
/some_backup/home/user1
/some_backup/home/user2
/some_backup/home/user3
```

…of which the `user2` and `user3` directories are filled by another rsync from another computer. Unfortunately, this rsync line does not work, since my rsync call will delete `/some_backup/home/user3` (because this is not present in my /home) and also `/some_backup/home/user2` (because this is a out-of-fs symlink).

Is there a way to tell rsync to ignore target directories that do not have a match in the source? I need the `--delete` because this behavior is required otherwise.

One possible solution is to have one rsync statement for every /home/user directory that has to be copied (rather than backup the entire /home). This is not ideal, since users come and go, which would require much more maintenance.